# custom radio button show value inside

Tags: php, html, css

I have customized radio buttons and they are working as I intended them with one exception. I want the value to be inside of the radio button div and right now it shows outside the radio button I created, which actually is a class big-radio. **How can I show the value 1 and value 2 inside the radio button I created**

below is my code

css:

```
<style>
    .ipad {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        border: 1px solid #cacece;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        padding: 9px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ipad:active, .ipad:checked:active {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    .ipad:checked {
        background-color: blue;
        border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        color: #99a1a7;
    }
    .ipad:checked:after {
        content: '\2714';
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 3px;
        color: transparent;
    }
    .big-radio {
        padding: 18px;
    }

    .big-radio:checked:after {
        font-size: 28px;
        left: 6px;
    }



</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button-holder">
    <input type="radio" class="ipad big-radio" name="radioGroup" value="2081764"/> Value1
</div>
<div class="button-holder">
    <input type="radio" class="ipad big-radio" name="radioGroup" value="2081765"/> Value 2
</div>
```

please find the jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4fu3q/

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What's the "point"?

Comment: I am trying to put the text in the radio button css that I created

Comment: You can't; an input element can't contain any child nodes (not even text^1). If you need this, then you need to wrap the `input` with a `div` (or `span`), and place the text inside *that* element, as a sibling to the `input`. **1:** Though an `input type="text"` *can* contain a value, which is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd use data-attributes:

Use an html attribute to each input: `<input data-value="Value Text">`

and then in your css: `.ipad:before { content: attr(data-value); }`

http://jsfiddle.net/4fu3q/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of fake it, though it's far from ideal.  If you use a `label` you can overlay the text over the radiobutton without losing its clickability.  Something like the following is one example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4fu3q/2/

```
<div class="button-holder">
    <input type="radio" class="ipad big-radio"  name="radioGroup" value="2081764" id="one">  
    <label for="one">V1</label>
</div>
```

---

```
label{
    position:relative;
    left: -35px;    
    top: -10px;
}
```

The button obviously won't re-size to fit the text as it is not actually inside of it.  It's far from ideal but may be about as close as you can get without replacing everything with javascript.